# Copying DCIM/Camera images causes hang/reboot

Tags: usb, windows, crashes, 5.1-lollipop

In 5.1.1 lollipop, I'm trying to transfer to a Windows 7 PC via USB some 19GB of images/videos using either Windows copy or Picasa Import. Whether or not I use MTP (Media device) or PTP (Camera) on USB, the result is the same:

- after some time 4+ minutes, the connection drops;
- it's not always the same file that is copying when the failure occurs;
- the phone becomes unresponsive -- sometimes the screen freezes, sometimes everything just slows down;
- eventually, Android reboots.

I have Android Studio and looked at the `adb` log. Here are messages just around the crash time (I think the stack trace is when Android reboots):

```
08-29 17:21:44.108      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ TM Id 'SKIN_THERMAL_management_1' Sensor 'xo_therm_pu2' - alarm raised 1 at 40.0 degC
08-29 17:21:44.112      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[0] to 1958400
08-29 17:21:44.112      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[1] to 1958400
08-29 17:21:44.112      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[2] to 1958400
08-29 17:21:44.112      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[3] to 1958400
08-29 17:21:44.123      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ ACTION: LCD - Setting max LCD brightness to 229
08-29 17:22:05.211      906-906/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 3428 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-29 17:22:06.098      199-264/? I/ThermalEngine﹕ TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm raised 2 at 340.0 degC
08-29 17:22:06.111      199-264/? E/ThermalEngine﹕ override action 7500
08-29 17:22:06.112      199-264/? E/ThermalEngine﹕ Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg override 7500
08-29 17:22:06.115      199-264/? E/ThermalEngine﹕ override_notify : SS mode 1 override 7500
08-29 17:22:19.346      745-813/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 906 SIG: 3
08-29 17:22:19.349     745-1049/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 745 SIG: 3
08-29 17:22:19.354      745-751/? I/art﹕ Thread[5,tid=751,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4828c00,peer=0x12c020a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
08-29 17:22:19.354      906-916/? I/art﹕ Thread[5,tid=916,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4a23000,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
08-29 17:22:19.356      745-751/? I/art﹕ [ 08-29 17:22:19.356   906:  916 I/art      ]
08-29 17:22:19.385      745-751/? W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 28.517ms
08-29 17:23:14.174      906-916/? I/art﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Because the device is not rooted, I can't view `/data/anr/traces.txt`.

I see a [similar problem has been logged in the Picasa forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/fPPf90rl3Vo). There's also one [reported on Androide.SE here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/82010/87547).

Is my device overheating?